# Opencv python crashes after certain time

Tags: python, opencv, libpng

In my code after certain time (depend of the PC or OS) crashes. The error displayed is

```
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
```

My code draw ROI on a video from webcam and take a snapshot. The ROI is deleted after 5-10 minutes (I'm not sure why, this is the error) and the picture saved not have dimensions then the error above is displayed but I'm not find the error. The instructions are, press "c" to stop the video and draw a ROI, press again "c" to take the picture, press "r" to resume the video, and repeat if you need another pictures. 
I tested the code in Windows 10 and raspbian on a raspberry and the time is not the same but on both the program crashes. This is my code:

```
import cv2

# python PSI_Camera_test.py


class staticROI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
        # Bounding box reference points and boolean if we are extracting coordinates
        self.image_coordinates = []
        self.extract = False
        self.selected_ROI = False
        self.img_counter = 0
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                # Read frame
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
                cv2.imshow('image', self.frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(2)

                # Crop image
                if key == ord('c'):
                    self.clone = self.frame.copy()
                    cv2.namedWindow('image')
                    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', self.extract_coordinates)
                    while True:
                        key = cv2.waitKey(2)
                        cv2.imshow('image', self.clone)

                        # Crop and display cropped image
                        if key == ord('c'):
                            self.crop_ROI()
                            img_name = "Images\opencv_frame_{}.png".format(
                                self.img_counter)
                            cv2.imwrite(img_name, self.cropped_image)
                            print("{} written!".format(img_name))
                            self.img_counter += 1

                        # Resume video
                        if key == ord('r'):
                            break
                # Close program with keyboard 'esp'
                if key % 256 == 27:
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    exit(1)
            else:
                pass

    def extract_coordinates(self, event, x, y, flags, parameters):
        # Record starting (x,y) coordinates on left mouse button click
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.image_coordinates = [(x, y)]
            self.extract = True

        # Record ending (x,y) coordintes on left mouse bottom release
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            self.image_coordinates.append((x, y))
            self.extract = False

            self.selected_ROI = True

            # Draw rectangle around ROI
            cv2.rectangle(
                self.clone, self.image_coordinates[0], self.image_coordinates[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Clear drawing boxes on right mouse button click
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
            self.clone = self.frame.copy()
            self.selected_ROI = False

    def crop_ROI(self):
        if self.selected_ROI:
            self.cropped_image = self.frame.copy()

            x1 = self.image_coordinates[0][0]
            y1 = self.image_coordinates[0][1]
            x2 = self.image_coordinates[1][0]
            y2 = self.image_coordinates[1][1]

            self.cropped_image = self.cropped_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]

            print('Cropped image: {} {}'.format(
                self.image_coordinates[0], self.image_coordinates[1]))
        else:
            print('Select ROI to crop before cropping')


# python PSI_Camera_test.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    static_ROI = staticROI()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ran your code on a video file with no errors. Can you add a check for `self.status == True` before accessing the frame. Maybe the webcam sometimes fails to capture a frame and you get the error you're seeing

Comment: Thanks for response! I just tried with some videos and the error still appears.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this error by shutting down the webcam. The code failed at `cv2.imshow` line. So `self.status == True` is something that should be in this code. But, obviously your problem derives from another source. Your `crop_ROI` function looked kind of faulty. I tested it out. Tried drawing a ROI from right-bottom corner to left-up corner. It did not work, expectedly. ROI from right-up corner and left-bottom works but not the other way around. Could this be your problem?

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl Thanks! In fact, the function ```crop_ROI``` have that characteristics, but isn't the problem, the problem is that the ROI vanishes after certain time and the image taken is empty.

Comment: @AugustoMeneses it seems like you have an issue with your opencv installation since none of us are able to replicate your issue. Try re-installing opencv using steps listed on sites like pyimagesearch.

Comment: Do you have this issue when you are saving as jpg? What are the exact steps for this error?

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm save as .png. I'm run the code, draw a ROI, take a snapshot, resume the video, take another snapshot, and after many snapshots, the program says the error above and I'm need to draw the ROI again.

Comment: I asked "Do you have the same issue while saving files in jpg format?".